# Why are secret spots mising in the Wii version of Zelda I?

Tags: the-legend-of-zelda

I'm just wondering if anybody else that has downloaded the original Legend of Zelda on their Wii or Wii U has noticed thats it's not the same as the original cartridge version.

None of the secret spots are there. Spots where you would either blow up some rock walls with a bomb or burn a bushs to find secret spots aren't there in the Wii version.

Why not? Are they in new spots or just not there anymore?

Answer (score 6):

You have experienced the [**Second Quest**](http://zeldawiki.org/Second_Quest).

The Second Quest is unlocked after beating the game. Dungeons, some shops, and Heart Containers are found at different locations on the map, along with the difficulty level being higher. The Second Quest was created because the developers had only used half of the allotted space for the map, and decided to use the other half for another quest.

It is possible to play the Second Quest right away by entering the name "**ZELDA**" when starting a new game.